# plot gridsearch csv results how?

Tags: python, visualization, cross-validation, plotting, grid-search

how can i plot my results from gridsearch csv?

```
clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=3,return_train_score=True)
clf.fit(x, y)
df = pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_)
```

i'm trying to get a similar plot to what is here: https://matthewbilyeu.com/blog/2019-02-05/validation-curve-plot-from-gridsearchcv-results , but this uses the grid search object and i have tried and failed at trying to get the same using just the gridsearch df (from above).

can anybody help in how i go about this?

Comment: Why do you fail? With that  you get a pandas dataframe, if you extract the parameters (I think they are in dic format) you should be able do a fast plot

Comment: aram_ranges = [grid.param_grid[p[6:]] for p in param_cols] <-- you need the grid object here what would be qeuivalent for df

Answer (score 0):

Pass your clf object to the function provided in the website. It should work.